# redux-saga doesn't work at the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a redux-saga as below:

```
export function* loadApplianceSaga() {
  try {
    let {request, success, error} = yield take(ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD);
    request.url = yield select(getResourceLink, request.resource);
    const response = yield call(makeRequest, request);
    if (!response.error) {
      yield put({type: success, payload: response.body});
    } else {
      yield put({type: error, payload: response});
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({type: ActionTypes.REQUEST.CALL_ERROR, error: e});
  }
}

export function* watchLoadAppliance() {
  while (true) {
    yield* takeEvery(ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD, loadApplianceSaga);
  }
}
```

and root saga:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    fork(watchLoadAppliance)
  ]
}
```

I'm facing a problem that `loadApplianceSaga` doesn't work at the first time. I logged and saw that in the first time it only dispatched `ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD` action then no action is dispatched. But in the second time, I can see success action or failed action which are dispatched.

Could anyone tell me what was wrong? Thanks in advance!

**Updated action**:

```
export const loadAppliances = () => {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD,
    request: {
      resource: Resources.Appliances,
      param: {
        page: 0,
        size: 5,
        sort: 'name,desc'
      },
      header: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    },
    success: ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD_SUCCESS,
    error: ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD_ERROR
  }
};
```

Comment: does the action include {request, success, error} ?

Comment: Yes, the action include all of them.

Comment: I've added action. @Utro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have used `take` two times.
try

```
export function* loadApplianceSaga(action) {
  try {
    let {request, success, error} = action;
    request.url = yield select(getResourceLink, request.resource);
    const response = yield call(makeRequest, request);
    if (!response.error) {
      yield put({type: success, payload: response.body});
    } else {
      yield put({type: error, payload: response});
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({type: ActionTypes.REQUEST.CALL_ERROR, error: e});
  }
}

export function* watchLoadAppliance() {
  while (true) {
    yield* takeEvery(ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD, loadApplianceSaga);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works. Could you explain a little bit why I met this problem? I'm new to redux-saga.

Comment: also i think, you shouldn't mutate the action @AnNguyen

Comment: oh, I will consider it. Thanks!

Comment: about the problem.. I think, you have tried to get the action through additional `take` effect in loadApplianceSaga, but `takeEvery` allready pass it to loadApplianceSaga @AnNguyen